# Configured Simplesamlphp as SP and Idp but not able to login to idp server

Tags: php, saml-2.0

I have configured 2 saml servers, one as SP and another as IDP.
Also configured both metadata to initiate communication between both the servers.
Now when I am trying to Test authentication sources as default-sp, it navigtes to Idp server but throws error -

Debug information
The debug information below may be of interest to the administrator / help desk:

```
SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION

Backtrace:
1 www/_include.php:45 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: No such "studentpass" auth 
source found.
Backtrace:
2 lib/SimpleSAML/IdP.php:108 (SimpleSAML_IdP::__construct)
1 lib/SimpleSAML/IdP.php:139 (SimpleSAML_IdP::getById)
0 www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php:17 (N/A)
```

Please help me how to proceed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error says `SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION`

Comment: Resolved by my own.
Metadata path was not correct.

Comment: great work dear ..

Comment: Thanks :) @MittulAtTechnoBrave